# Memory issues when writing data to dask array

Tags: memory, dask, netcdf, python-xarray, chunks

I have a script loading a .nc file and writing the data into a newly created dask array. The data variable of the nc file has the dimensions 'time', 'y' and 'x'. The dask array has the additional dimension 'step'. While writing the data to the dask array the memory gets eaten up until the process is killed.

This is my script. The new dask array should contain the data values of the nc file and NaNs for the timesteps, for which no data is available from the nc file.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
import dask.array as da
import dask
dask.config.set(scheduler='single-threaded')

# Load the netCDF file using xarray
nc_file = xr.open_dataset('data.nc')

# Set the time coordinate as the index
nc_file = nc_file.set_index(time='time')

# Create a new time coordinate with hourly frequency
start_time = nc_file.time[0].values
end_time = nc_file.time[-1].values
new_time = pd.date_range(start=start_time, end=end_time, freq='1H')

# Create a new empty Dataset with the new time coordinate
new_data = xr.Dataset(coords={'time': new_time})

# Create step variable
s_start, s_stop, s_resolution = "0H", "0H", "1H"  # 1H for hourly
step = pd.timedelta_range(start=s_start, end=s_stop, freq=s_resolution).to_numpy()

# Create a new empty DataArray for the data variable with the new time coordinate and the same dimensions as the data variable
dims = ('step','time', 'y', 'x')

# Define the size of the array
size = (1, len(new_time), len(new_data.y), len(new_data.x))

# Create a dask array filled with NaNs
data = da.full(size, np.nan, chunks=(1,100, len(new_data.y), len(new_data.x)))

new_data = xr.DataArray(data=data, coords=[step,new_time, new_data.y, new_data.x], dims=dims)

# Fill in the new DataArray with the data from the netCDF file where the time step exists
for t in nc_file.time.values:
    if t in new_data.time.values:
        new_data.loc[{'time': t}] = nc_file.data.sel(time=t).where(nc_file.data.sel(time=t) >= 0, np.nan).expand_dims(dim='step', axis=0).values


...
```

I tried diefferent chunk sizes for dask array, but I always had the problem that the process got killed. I am thankful for every advice how to avoid these memory issues

Comment: I think you are using the wrong approach for creating your Dask Array. You shouldn't try to assign chunks to an already created array. You should create your array in a lazy manner, see https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/array-creation.html#using-dask-delayed.